# How do I setup multiple type bounds in Scala?

Tags: generics, scala

I want to be able to declare something like this:

```
trait Narrowable[A] extends Iterable[A] {

    def narrow[B <: A & B <: AnyRef] : Iterable[B]

}
```

That it, the type `B` should be both a subtype of `A` *and* `AnyRef`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Use Compound Type:

```
trait Narrowable[A] extends Iterable[A] {
  def narrow[B <: A with AnyRef] : Iterable[B]
}
```

Comment: Same deal, digging for gold, years later one finds the insightful replies of Walter Chang ;-)

Comment: @Walter Chang how  about **or/any one of the two upper bounds**  `def narrow[B <: A | B <: AnyRef] : Iterable[B]`

Comment: @PushpendraJaiswal Your best bet is probably to simply use `Either[A, AnyRef]` rather than type bounds.

Comment: What if you need an upper bound, and a context bound?

Comment: @Thayne then you declare both. First the upper bound, then the context bound (following a colon)