# Multiple lower type bounds in Scala

Tags: scala, jvm, type-systems

I noticed that `tuple.productIterator` always returns an `Iterator[Any]` an wondered if it's not possible to set multiple lower bounds (so it could be an Iterator of the lowest common super type).

I tried and searched a bit, but only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491283/how-do-i-setup-multiple-type-bounds-in-scala) question for multiple upper bounds.

This is my test on how to define the the type of the iterator:

```
def f[A,B](a:A, b:B) = List(a,b)
// return type is List[Any]

def f[A,B, T >: A "and" T >: B](a:A, b:B) = List[T](a,b)
// doesn't compile, but
//  f(1, true) should give a List[AnyVal] and
//  f("x", "y") a List[String]
```

Is this a limitation of the JVM?

---

*Edit:*
Here's a slightly bigger example which doesn't seem to be solvable using IttayD approach when T should be defined in the method:

```
class Foo[A, B](a: A, b: B) {
  def f[T >: A] = List[T](a) // works
  def g[T >: A "and" T >: B] = List[T](a) // doesn't work
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the simple case where `A` and `B` are bound by the compiler as the same time as `T`, [IttayD's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117999/multiple-lower-type-bounds-in-scala/6120222#6120222) works fine:

```
def f[T, A <: T,B <: T](a:A, b:B) = List[T](a,b)
```

When `A` and `B` are already bound as in your `class Foo[A, B]` example, you need to introduce temporary dummy variables to have the compiler do this job:

```
class Foo[A, B](a: A, b: B) {
  def g[T, A1 >: A <: T, B1 >: B <: T] = List[T](a: A1, b: B1)
}
```

*(For the sake of clarity: `A1 >: A <: T` means that type `A1` must be a supertype of `A` and a subtype of `T`, and not that `A` is a subtype of both `A1` and `T`.)*

`A1` and `B1` are here for the sole purpose of inferring a correct type for `T`. If the compiler has to infer them, they will resolve to `A1 = A` and `B1 = B`, and then `T` as the most specific type which is a superclass of both `A` and `B`.

One thing that the compiler doesn't realize, though, is that, by transitivity, we have both `T >: A` and `T >: B`, which follows directly from the constraints with respect to `A1` and `B1`. We need to help out with the type ascriptions.

Now, `Product#productIterator` could not use this technique, as it's defined in a place where we don't even know `A` and `B`, or indeed how many type parameters there are in the concrete subclass.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like what you need is an HList: http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/type-level-programming-in-scala-part-6a-heterogeneous-list%C2%A0basics/

To answer the specific question:

```
scala> def f[T, A <: T,B <: T](a:A, b:B) = List[T](a,b)
f: [T, A <: T, B <: T](a: A, b: B)List[T]

scala> f(1, true)
res0: List[AnyVal] = List(1, true)

scala> f("x", "y")
res1: List[java.lang.String] = List(x, y)
```

Comment: This is almost equivalent to a simple `def f[T](a:T, b:T) = List[T](a,b)`…

Comment: f(1,2.0) will result in List[Double] = List(1.0, 2.0)

Comment: What if `A` and `B` were defined in an outer scope? Would I need to move the definition of T also to that outer scope? (@IttayD fixed the example)

Comment: @IttayD Your update is dangerous: look at the return type, a `List[Int with Double]`… Funny type. You make the compiler believe it's a list of elements that are **all both Ints and Doubles**. Try this and get an unwanted `ClassCastException`: `val res = (new Foo(1, "hi")).g; res.head.size`

Comment: The fact that type ascription doesn't work is a hint that the compiler is not happy with it.

Comment: @IttayD Check my answer for a solution without HLists.