# Scala Lower Bounds Error: value is not a member of type parameter

Tags: scala, types, scala-compiler

The scala compiler seems to give false type-errors for statements with multiple lower bounds.

Given class `Foo` with the method `g` using a lower bound for `A` and `B`

```
class Foo[A, B](a: A, b: B) {
  def g[T, A1 >: A <: T, B1 >: B <: T] = List[T](a: A1, b: B1)
}
```

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6124549, and classes `X`, `Y <: X` and `Z <: X`,

```
abstract class X {def a: String}
object Y extends X {def a = "this is Y"}
object Z extends X {def a = "this is Z"}
```

the following code works fine, as expected:

```
Y.a
new Foo(Y,Z).g
new Foo(Y,Z).g.head // instance of Y, type X
new Foo(Y,Z).g.head.isInstanceOf[X] // true
new Foo(Y,Z).g.head.asInstanceOf[X].a
new Foo(Y,Z).g[X,Y.type,Z.type].head.a
new Foo(Y,Z).g[X,X,X].head.a
{val y = new Foo(Y,Z).g.head; y}.a
```

Surprisingly,

```
new Foo(Y,Z).g.head.a
```

does **not**! (tested in Scala 2.12.7, 2.12.8, 2.13.0-M5, but it does work as expected in Dotty)

It yields `error: value a is not a member of type parameter T`.

Is this a bug in the compiler or is there a specific reason, why I cannot call `a` on `new Foo(Y,Z).g.head`?

`y` gets the type `X`, so the compiler *can* obviously figure out that `new Foo(Y,Z).g.head` is of type `X`, and I do not get, why assigning it to a new value and calling the method on that helps the type-checker. Also, I think, explicitly casting to `X` should not change anything, but it does.

[Try online!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/mjxj58HPS9K9E2cdkrKKRQ)

Comment: it doesn't really answer your question. But this works too `new Foo(Y,Z).g[X,Y.type,Z.type].head.a`

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to test that. Have included it in the question now.